# How to setup sitecore site from existing database and website folder?

Tags: configuration, sim, settings

I have a database and website folder backup provided by the client. How can I configure a sitecore site manually or by using the Sitecore Instance Manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For an existing site, you would want to create the site manually in IIS.

- Create a new website in IIS, point the folder to your `website` folder.
- Make sure the binding is setup to something like `mywebsite.local`.
- Make sure the permissions on the website folder are set to allow the AppPool user for your new website to have read & write access.
- Restore the database
- Update the `/app_config/ConnectionStrings.config` file with your database connection details
- Make sure the data folder is set correctly `/app_config/include/datafolder.config`
- Update the site definition to include your host name in the binding.

That should allow you to load up the site, then you can rebuild the indexes and should be ready to go.

Answer (score 5):

@Richard Seal's answer is entirely correct, but if you are worried about setting IIS and NTFS security things manually, you can also follow these steps:

1. Install a fresh Sitecore instance like you normally would using SIM or the installer.
2. Replace the installed Website folder with the Website folder you received from the client.

Then proceed as with the final steps that Richard highlighted:

3. Restore the database
4. Update the /app_config/ConnectionStrings.config file with your database connection details
5. Make sure the data folder is set correctly /app_config/include/datafolder.config
6. Update the site definition to include your host name in the binding.

Comment: I was going to recommend this approach if you didn't, although there's nothing wrong with Richard's response, this would get the user to the end result quicker and with less hassle.